# Trying to SELECT a record in an sqlite database using php

Tags: php, sqlite

I am trying to select one record from the table tblTermDate. I am only getting an output of 1 for both. There is data entered into the fields and the format is VARCHAR for both dates. Any help would be appreciated Thanks!

```
<?php
// create or open database called TimeTable.sqlite
$db = @sqlite_open("TimeTable.sqlite");
//Get Start Date from Table
$StartDate = @sqlite_exec($db, "SELECT fldStartDate FROM tblTermDate WHERE fldTerm_Name ='Christmas 1st Half' ");
//Print Start Date
echo $StartDate;
echo "<br> </br>";
//Get Start Date from Table
$EndDate = @sqlite_exec($db, "SELECT fldEndDate FROM tblTermDate WHERE fldTerm_Name ='Christmas 1st Half' ");
//Print End Date
echo $EndDate;

//Database Close
@sqlite_close($db);
?>
```

Comment: Did you read the [documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.sqlite-exec.php)? sqlite_exec returns 1 if the statement succeeds.

Answer (score 0):

sqlite_exec executes a SQL statement and does not return any rows. Its return value is true if the statement was executed successfully and false otherwise. Hence your "output" of 1. 
What you are looking for is the sqlite_query method: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.sqlite-query.php